# why cant I use a string when concatenating a url for Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

**question updated, see below**

I'm trying to scrape city and state given zip code.  Here's code that works:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.city-data.com/zips/11021.html")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
main_body = soup.find(id="main_body").findAll('a')[5].string
print main_body
```

I get the following, correct string:

```
Great Neck Plaza, NY
```

the following code does not (it prints the wrong string):

```
zipCode = str(10023)
url = "http://www.city-data.com/zips/" + zipCode + ".html"
print url
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
main_body = soup.find(id="main_body").findAll('a')[5].string
print main_body
```

here's the wrong string:

```
Recent home sales, real estate maps, and home value estimator for zip code 10023
```

Why cant I use a string for the zip code?  What else can I do, as I'm trying to write a function to look up city and state?

**UPDATE**

Per some suggestions, i'm now searching for the text immediately prior to the tag I want. here is the text i'm searching for followed by the info I actually want:

```
<b>City:</b>
 <a href="/city/New-York-New-York.html">New York, NY</a>
```

here is the code i'm not trying:

```
zipCode = str(11021)
url = "http://www.city-data.com/zips/" + zipCode + ".html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
main_body = soup.findAll(text="City:")
print main_body
```

All I get, however, are empty brackets.  How do I search for the `City:` text and then get the string for the next tag?

Comment: What went wrong? Any error or you just get an unexpected result?

Comment: unexpected result.  The first one yields the city and state.  The second returns some other string.

Comment: @dwstein: And you're sure this is caused by making `zipCode` a variable?

Comment: @Blender:  no, I'm not sure.  it's just the only think I've changed (I think).

Comment: Can you show what string are you getting in the second example, and what is it in the first example? I think i'm getting it.

Comment: @aIKid: I edited the question to add the strings.

Comment: From this pages, which link are you exactly trying to get?

Comment: @aIKid: i'm trying to write a function to get the city and state given a zip code.  My first code snippet works.  My second snippet is an attempt to make the code more generic so I can use different zip codes.

Comment: That's not what i meant haha. I see that there are multiple cities there, which one do you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, but the premise of your solution is not correct.  Your code (`findAll('a')[5]`) assumes that the data you're after is going to be in the same place for every zip code page.  However, if you look at the pages for zips 11021 and 10023, you'll see that they don't have the same number of hyperlinks.  You need to find another way to locate the data than simply grabbing index 5 of the array of hyperlinks on the page.

Comment: nice catch!  any thoughts on how I can better locate what i'm looking for?

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail about what you're after.  The output that you said was correct is the third city of about a dozen listed cities.  IOW - each zip is going to have a different number of listed cities.  Some will have just one and some will have many.  Do you want all of them?  Just one in particular?

Comment: Then that would mean that the example that you said was correct is actually NOT correct, since it was the third city, not the first.

Comment: I'm sure you're right.  I'm a n00b stabbing around in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

here's code that worked for me:

```
zipCode = str("07928")
url = "http://www.city-data.com/zips/" + zipCode + ".html"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
if soup.findAll(text="City:") ==[]:
    cityNeeded = soup.findAll(text="Cities:")
    for t in cityNeeded:
        print t.find_next('a').string
else:
    cityNeeded = soup.findAll(text="City:")
    for t in cityNeeded:
        print t.find_next('a').string
```